# import mysql.connector: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql, xampp

I'm trying to run XAMPP Apache and MySQL on my Windows 11 PC, and when I do it runs ok, but when I try to access any .py files by browser (localhost/cgi-bin/examples/exercise5/main.py i get this import mysql.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module names 'mysql' (... -> path to the file I entered in the browser), even though `mysql` and `mysql.connector` have been installed. I even ran `pip3 install mysql-connector-python-rf` . Now, the funniest thing is that none of the files and their respective methods use mysql.

Thanks all in advance